# Blender export to FBX issue

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, export, .fbx

So I created a really basic character and made a simple animation for it. The issue is when I try to export it to FBX the animation gets all scuffed up. I will attach the blend file and the images

.blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eiUhm9EvPTsy71Elt2CMYQHfByWwJpNg/view?usp=sharing

[image: Before exporting]
[image: After exporting]